# How to upload files to MS one drive using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

It's my first time to do the project and my project manager give me time to research how to do it. I came from google and some codes are too complicated, is there a simple way how to do it? or maybe not too complicated I guess.

Comment: Have you tried to code anything? If so, can you share that with us?

Comment: I didn't, I'm looking for a sample simple working code using vb.net maybe just a single button where the user can upload a file to ms one drive. Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
''' <summary>
''' Uploads a file to  Microsoft OneDrive.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="FilePath">Path of a file to upload from.</param>
''' <exception cref="KeyNotFoundException">The registry key of MS OneDrive is not found.</exception>
''' <returns>The path of file inside MS OneDrive folder.</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Function UploadToMSOneDrive(FilePath As String) As String
    Const keyName As String = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER" & "\\" & "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SkyDrive"
    Const DefaultKey As String = "OMG Teh ReGiStRy DOesn''''t E.x;I's|T!!!"
    Dim OneDrivePath As String = DirectCast(Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(keyName, "UserFolder", DefaultKey), String)
    Dim MSOneDriveProgram As String = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe")
    Dim Destination As String = IO.Path.Combine(If(OneDrivePath = DefaultKey, OneDrivePath, ThrowKeyNotFoundException("Is MS OneDrive not installed?")), IO.Path.GetFileName(FilePath))
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(FilePath, Destination)
    Process.Start(MSOneDriveProgram)
    Return Destination
End Function
Friend Function ThrowKeyNotFoundException(Message As String) As Type
    Throw New KeyNotFoundException(Message)
    Return GetType(Void) ' This will not be reached
End Function
```