# Uploading a file to One drive using VB.net using OneDrive API

Tags: vb.net, upload, onedrive

I am trying to upload a file generated by the process into OneDrive. I haven't started the code to share with you guys. I looked into google but couldn't find anything. I have to authenticate the user and the upload the file to a particular folder . I even tried to use

> Microsoft.onedrive.sdk

But I couldn't move any where can anyone please help me out . Pleas note that the upload accounts may change on based on the document produced .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read this: [ask].  This question is currently not suitable for this site.  You need to narrow it down, and unfortunately you need to try coding it yourself first.  If you have an issue after that, then you can ask about that issue.  Currently, this question is too broad.

Comment: about 1,800,000 hits if you Google your title

Comment: @Plutonix Funnily enough the top result for searching the title gives a complete code block of how to do it :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload files to MS one drive using vb.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516905/how-to-upload-files-to-ms-one-drive-using-vb-net)

Comment: Thank you . I have googled before coming here i researched for a day . Yes i have seen the code block in the first search result . But the code block doesn't work for my scenario . Because i don't have one drive installed on the serve r and also . the credentials will change every time .I need to perform a upload .  And the best case is which would work form me is available in the MSDN but using that i need to perform a signing every time. That's why I came here for help from experts.

Comment: I need help working with the onedrive API